# Why is the SpringApplication.run() inside the class that it runs?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm new to SpringBoot and I've been a long time without coding with Java. In my mind this doesn't make sense. Why is the `SpringApplication.run()` inside the class that it runs ?

Like so:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConsumingRestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConsumingRestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: "In my mind this doesn't make sense" why not?

Comment: Also, it's inside the class that *runs it*, not the class *it runs*. Could this be what confused you?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I don't know if its because I've been coding in JavaScript for a long time. But for me it would make more sense to call from the outside.

Comment: from outside of what? It's inside the `main` method of the main class of the application. What else should start the framework? (I'm not being flippant, I'm trying to understand what you expected instead and why)

Comment: I would rather prefer to see a class named something like `FrameworkIni` and inside that class execute the `SpringApplication.run(SomeApp.class, args)` method. That would make more sense to me.

Comment: And what would you then put inside the `SomeApp` class? Notice that the application logic in a Spring application does *not* go inside the main class.

Comment: Well, everything else related to that class.

Comment: Like what? And, again, what for? It just seems wasteful for no practical advantage to me.

Comment: Okay, I get it. But what I still don't understand is that this main class is been runed before the `SpringApplication.run()`is executed. So why run it again ? Please help me understand the logic.

Comment: There's nothing being run again here. The main class starts the framework. That's it. Nothing is being run twice.

Comment: Java needs `public static void main(String[] args) {...}` entry point to kick off. At this point there's no Spring, just pure Java. Then, Spring needs to kick off, so we invoke it with `SpringApplication.run(...)`. Only then, Spring annotations are being read, Spring beans created, etc. We could pass any class as a parameter here, but this same main class makes the most sense.

Comment: @sp00m thanks, it makes more sense. Wouldn't it be more logical to have a `public class AppIni {}` that starts `Spring` with `SpringApplication.run(myApp.class, args)` ?

Comment: @Gass maybe a more objective question would be [why do we need to pass `run` anything in the first place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62975942/purpose-of-class-argument-in-springapplication-run-class-args)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there is no practical need.

Technically you could do something like that:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConsumingRestApplication {}

public class Init {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConsumingRestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

But you wouldn't gain anything from it, that's why it's just simplified into one class with the annotation and the main method.

Comment: Thanks. Wouldn't it be more logical to have a public class AppIni {} that starts Spring with `SpringApplication.run(myApp.class, args)` ?

Comment: But that's exactly what i meant in my example. It wouldn't be more logical.

Comment: you are completely right! I didn't read you code the right way, I though the `Init` class was inside the `ConsumingRestApplication` class. didn't see the closing curly braces at the top. Thanks for your answer!