# SpringApplication.run: why do we need the "MyApplication.class" parameter when "@SpringBootApplication" annotation presents?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I always see Spring Boot main class as below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

      SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

Why does the SpringApplication.run method need a `MyApplication.class` argument?

Spring doc says:

> Parameters: primarySources - the primary sources to load

But when `@SpringBootApplication` presents, we already told Spring that the bean source is in the current package and its sub-packages because `@SpringBootApplication` includes `@ComponentScan`. I got his understanding from https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning:

> @ComponentScan without arguments tells Spring to scan the current
> package and all of its sub-packages.

So, when `@SpringBootApplication` presents, we should not need the  `MyApplication.class` parameter.

Why is that parameter required?

Did I mis-understand anything?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62975942/purpose-of-class-argument-in-springapplication-run-class-args

Comment: This post is NOT a duplicate of the link. The link was asking the purpose of the ".class" argument. But this post is asking a "seemingly" redundancy where both the "@SpringBootApplication" annotation and the argument "MyApplication.class" present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not tell it where to find the class that is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` , it needs to scan all packages to find it out which take lot of times.

So explicit tell it the location of `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class can make it find it much faster. It can then use it as the starting point to know which packages to scan next based on the configuration of its mete-annotation such as `@ComponentScan`

Comment: That does not sound right, since Spring doc says that the argument is to tell Spring the "primarySource" and (my understanding of) "primarySource" is the class(es) that contain bean definitions, e.g., the @Configuration annotated class(es). Note that, it is fine to replace the "MyApplication.class" argument with "SomeConfig.class" where "SomeConfig" contains bean definitions but not being annotated with "@SpringBootApplication".

Comment: I think this answer simply should be prepended with "If such method without arguments would've been existed, then ...".

`ComponentScan`, `SpringBootConfiguration`, `SpringBootApplication` and other similar annotations all are subset of `Configuration`s, so both @leo and @ken-chan are right.

Comment: yes. i know. i am intended to make my answer based on your question as I thought it would  let you understand more easily as your question focus on why need to explicitly tell spring-boot the location of `@SpringBootApplication` class. `@SpringBootApplication `is also a kind of `@Configuration` class.  You can simply replace the word `@SpringBootApplication` with `@Configuration` in my answer if it makes more sense to you.

Comment: Thank you @KenChan and @RomanMitasov. So, the parameter provide a starting point of component scan and we can include more, right? For example, if I have another ```@Configuration``` annotated class, say, ```AnotherConfig``` in another package, how to tell spring to also include it -- should I keep the ```MyApplication.class" argument and replace ```@SpringBootApplication``` with the 3 "mete-annotation (do you mean "meta"?)" and specify the package including ```AnotherConfig" in the ```@ComponentScan``` mete-annotation? Just want to make sure I fully understand your answers.

Comment: Yes. To specify more `@Configuration` class , there are version of `SpringApplication#run()` to accept an array of the `@Configuration` class. Another way is that  you can annotate `@Import({AnotherConfig.class})` on one of the `@Configuration` class that you input in the `SpringApplication#run()`